# Linux child process signal loss

Tags: c, signals, posix

I have two child processes and one parent process. The two child send a SIGUSR1 signal at the same time. The handler handles only one of them, and the parent receives only one of them too. I think it can be solved by using real time signal, but i don't now how to do it. Thank you for your help.

```
void handler(int signalnumber)
{
   //do stuff
}
int main()
{
   sigset_t blockset;
   sigfillset(&blockset);

   struct sigaction action;
   action.sa_handler = handler;
   sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
   sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

   pid_t pid = getpid();
   pid_t pids[2];

   for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   {
      if(getpid() == pid)
         pids[i] = fork();
   }

   if(getpid() != pid)
   {
       while(1)
       {
           kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
       }
   } else
   {
      while(1)
      {
          sigdelset(&blockset, SIGUSR1);
          sigsuspend(&blockset);
          //do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Edit: I replaced SIGUSR1 with SIGRTMIN+1. Now the handler receives both signals, but the parent does not. (I think, because it's not waiting for any.)

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, signals are not a good way to do it. But yes, using `SIGRTMIN` rather than `SIGUSR1` would probably avoid this one issue.

Comment: May you include a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

From `man sigaction`

```
sa_mask specifies a mask of signals  which  should  be  blocked  (i.e.,
added  to  the signal mask of the thread in which the signal handler is
invoked) during execution of the signal handler.  In addition, the sig‐
nal  which triggered the handler will be blocked, unless the SA_NODEFER
flag is used.`
```

So, use SA_NODEFER.

Comment: The handler receives both the signals, the problem is that the parent receives it only once.

Comment: @Daniel what does that mean? The handler runs in the parent.

Comment: If there is:
`void handler()
{
   printf("Handler\n");
}
...
if(getpid() != pid)
  ...   
  kill(getppid(), SIGRTMIN);
  ...
  else
  while(1)
      {
          sigdelset(&blockset, SIGUSR1);
          sigsuspend(&blockset);
          printf("Parent\n")
      }
   }
`
Then the handler writed twice, the parent writes once.

Comment: Maybe sigsuspend doesn't guarantee to return after just one signal has been processed, but until all of them (or some number, in a way like `pthread_cond_signal`). What does the man page say about this? If it does not specify it, it's a bug. Either in the implementation of sigsuspend or in the manual. (I think...)

Comment: The problem is, that the parent is processing the `printf` after the first signal and not waiting for the second one. Thus it does not affect the parent.